# Window function for is_unique?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unique

I'm looking to see if a value is unique in the column. For example:

```
; with tbl (value) as (
    select 'hello' UNION ALL
    select 'hello' UNION ALL
    select 'abc' UNION ALL
    select null
) select
    value,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE) = 1 value_is_unique
from tbl
```

And the result:

```
VALUE   VALUE_IS_UNIQUE
hello   FALSE
hello   FALSE
abc     TRUE
        TRUE
```

Is there a window function that basically does what I'm doing with the `COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE) = 1`? Or is the above the suggested way to do this?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html

Comment: Why `COUNT(COALESCE(value, ''))` and not `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @forpas oh that's interested, I didn't know that would work. Could you explain briefly why doing `COUNT(*)` works here? Oh I think I see -- even doing `COUNT(1)` would work as well.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` counts everything, even nulls. `COUNT(column_name)` counts only non-nulls in column_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in `is_unique` function. Counting and comparing to one, as you did, is probably the best approach to achieve this functionality.